# How to change material UI menu colours?

Tags: material-ui

I'm using material UI for  my React js project and **I want to change the outline color of menu**. If you know how to do please write down your answer.Thank you....

Comment: Can you please be more specific? By "outline color" which one exactly you mean? Being more specific will help you get more answers. Thanks

Comment: It means I want to change outline color of drop down menu in material UI.